# Ubuntu server postfix + dovecot authentication, wrong password

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, authentication, dovecot, thunderbird

I am trying to setup basic e-mail server just for me on my Ubuntu 12.04 following these guides.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot

I executed everything as it says in the tutorial. When I test with telnet from localhost everything seems fine, but when I try to connect with Thunderbird, it finds the settings automatically, even says that the certificate is invalid (which seems legit), but I get an error that my password is incorrect.

I can`t quite understand, is my mailbox linked with my linux account or I have to create a new user for this ? 
What can I do to see what the problem is ?

I have almost no idea what I am doing, so ... any help will be usefull.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can check authorization with `doveadm` command. Log in tou your mail server and type:

`doveadm auth username`

then enter the password. If no luck, try `doveadm auth username@domain.tld` - it depends on your setup.

If both commands fail, check if such user exist: `doveadm user username` or with domain.

If it fails too, the check your config files and lookups.

Comment: When I execute:

doveadm auth username

this is what I get:

Password: 
doveadm(username): Error: auth: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-client) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(username) egid=1000(username) missing +r perm: /var/run/dovecot/auth-client, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)

Any ideas what this shoud mean ?

Comment: Okay, then run `sudo chmod a+r /var/run/dovecot/auth-client` and try one more time. If succeed, now you know the reason. And do not forget to tighten up the permissions of that file after that.

Comment: When I execute this as root I get: doveadm(root): Error: auth: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-client) failed: Connection refused

Comment: Check if `dovecot` is running: `/etc/init.d/dovecot status`. If it is stopped, run: `sudo /etc/init.d/dovecot start`

Comment: I changed all permissions, now when I try doveadm auth I see:
passdb: gotha auth succeeded
extra fields:
  user=gotha
but the problem with Thunderbird remains. Anything else I may want to test ?

Comment: At least, your dovecot setup seems to be fine. Are you experiencing Thunderbird issue when trying to fetch mail or to send?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7967/discussion-between-gotha-and-slimsuperhero)

Comment: not sure if this is because a different version of dovecot, but I have to use `doveadm auth login username`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documents you've followed, you've configured your server to use PAM for authentication, which means yes, your email accounts are connected to use local accounts.

Answer (score 0):

On Thunderbird security.tls.version.min is 3 by default.
If is an old postfix / dovecot, you have to set security.tls.version.min to 1 or to upgrade postfix , dovecot.